# What is the difference between `bind`, `inflate` and `setContentView` in `DataBindingUtil`

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-jetpack

I have seen `DataBindingUtil` used with all three methods, and it is not clear from the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil) what the difference is between the three.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`bind`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil#bind(android.view.View)) takes an already inflated view hierarchy and returns a `ViewDataBinding` for it.

[`inflate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil#inflate(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)) takes a layout resource ID, *inflates a view hierarchy from it* and returns a `ViewDataBinding` for it. It's essentially equal to

```
val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, ...)
val binding = DataBindingUtil.bind<SomeLayoutBinding>(view)
```

[`setContentView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil#setContentView(android.app.Activity,%20int)) takes a layout resource ID, inflates a view hierarchy from it, *sets it as an activity content* and returns a `ViewDataBinding` for the inflated view hierarchy. It's essentially equal to

```
setContentView(R.layout.some_layout)
val view = findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)
val binding = DataBindingUtil.bind<SomeLayoutBinding>(view)
```

Comment: Is this necessary to call inflate before bind or we can skip it?

Comment: `LayoutInflater.inflate` + `SomeLayoutBinding.bind` = `SomeLayoutBinding.inflate`. It depends which on `inflate` you mean.

Comment: I meant skip `SomeLayoutBinding.inflate` and call `SomeLayoutBinding.bind`

Comment: View binding is a typesafe accessor to a view hierarchy. Inflate creates a view hierarchy from an XML layout. View binding without a view hierarchy doesn't make sense. Try what you propose and see what happens for yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Generaly **setContentView** () will be displayed in the **activity.**

but fragments have a lifecycle method called onCreateView which returns a view. The most common way to do this is to inflate a view in XML and return it(as may you see in fragment's java code). In this case you need to inflate it yourself. Fragments don't have a setContentView method. so **inflate** use for **fragments**.

and binding just bind a view to a layout.